# React native: Checking if a Third-Party App is Installed

Tags: android, ios, react-native

In react-native, I need to check if navigation apps are installed on the user's device. The app (for iOS and Android) should display a menu showing all the navigation apps available (e.g., Google Maps, Waze, Sygic, TomTom, etc.), and when an item is clicked, the corresponding app should be opened with directions. Is it possible to do this with react? Can we determine which apps are installed on the user's phone?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In React Native, you can check if a third-party app is installed on a device by using the **react-native-installed-apps** package. This package allows you to query the device for installed apps and perform actions based on the results.

Comment: Thanks Waseem for your response. Is this the package? [link](https://github.com/danilrafiqi/react-native-installed-application). I must add something on info.plist and Androidmanifest.xml? It seems that this package works only for android, I need a solution for iOS and Android

Comment: Yes Daniele, the link is right and it is only for android.

Comment: @Daniele I posted a new answer which works for both Android and IOS